# wordpress install on same domain with laravel on apache ubuntu

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, laravel-5.3

I have installed wordpress with laravel 5.3 in `news` directory inside /var/www/html/public/news/ folder.

`mydomain.com/news` will redirect to `mydomain.com/public/news/` as an 404 error page by wordpress.
Although `mydomain.com/news/` some normally.

So, what is the cause behind and how to resolve it?

My .htaccess files are as follows:

root directory `/var/www/html/`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

`/var/www/html/public/` directory

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

        RewriteCond $1 !^(news)

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

`/var/www/html/public/news/` directory

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /news/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /news/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: can you try by doing 2 thing first remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` form laravel `.htaccess`, and then remove extra slash `/` form WP `.htaccess` `RewriteBase /news`.

Comment: not it won't work at all